# How to add additional dependencies to php-buildpack in CloudFoundry

Tags: cloud-foundry, swisscomdev

We use the PHP-Buildpack to run our app on a CloudFoundry Service.

To Backup the Database we wan't to use the `mysqldump` command, therefore we need a way to install `mysql-client` in the buildpack.

Do we have to create our own php build-pack every time we need a custom dependencies or is there a easier way to install additional dependencies in the buildpack?

Comment: have a look at https://github.com/cloudfoundry/apt-buildpack. This should work, I didn't try out myself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some testing with the apt-buildpack (thank's to @FyodorGlebov) i have found a working solution.

1. add `apt.yml` in the project root ([documentation](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/apt-buildpack))

   ```
   ---
   packages:
   - mysql-client
   ```
2. add `multi-buildpack.yml` in the project root ([documentation](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/multi-buildpack))

   ```
   buildpacks:
   - https://github.com/cloudfoundry/apt-buildpack
   - https://github.com/cloudfoundry/php-buildpack
   ```
3. Push your app with this command ([documentation](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/multi-buildpack))

   ```
   cf push APP_NAME -b https://github.com/cloudfoundry/multi-buildpack
   ```

Comment: You don't need `multi-buildpack` buildpack unless you're stuck using a really old version of Cloud Foundry.  It's a little awkward, but the platform supports this automatically now:  https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/use-multiple-buildpacks.html.

Comment: Can confirm Daniels comment: By now it is sufficient to do step one (»add apt.yml«) and either add the »apt-buildpack« to the manifest file (see https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/manifest-attributes.html#buildpack) OR push the app with multiple buildpack arguments (`cf push APP_NAME -b https://github.com/cloudfoundry/apt-buildpack -b https://github.com/cloudfoundry/php-buildpack`). I prefer adding the buildpacks to the manifest file.